# output python dataframe to excel and create a new data_validation column in the exported excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, validation

context:
i have a dataframe that i want to export into an excel workbook. i want the excel to have an additional column (that is not in the dataframe) that is a data validated column in the workbook - i want it to only take in the range 1-9.

dataframe looks something like this:

| name | year |
| --- | --- |
| trixie | 1985 |
| timmy | 1990 |
| chester | 1993 |

I want the exported excel sheet to look like this: where the `code` column only allows a number between 1 and 9 (the excel data validation way) I want to do all of this in python.

| name | year | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| trixie | 1985 |  |
| timmy | 1990 |  |
| chester | 1993 |  |

Please help. THANKS in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with [`worksheet.data_validation`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_data_validate.html) from [xlswriter](/questions/tagged/xlswriter) :

```
df["code"] = None
items = list(range(1,10))
max_row, max_col = df.shape

with pd.ExcelWriter("/tmp/file.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="Sheet1", startrow=0)
    
    wb = writer.book
    ws = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
    
    ws.data_validation(f"C2:C{str(max_row+2)}", {"validate": "list", "source": items})
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: how could i add this as a new sheet to an existing workbook without it overwriting my old data?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a new column before exporting to excel:

```
df.assign(code='').to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

It's not possible to apply some constraints on the columns (without pain) in Python. Maybe you can use a macro or `openpyxl` to write an xlsm file.